# How to read cookies from client device using ESp8266 Webserver?

Tags: html, cookies, arduino, webserver, esp8266

I have written a simple HTML + JS code, where the user has to enter his name in a form, and it will be saved as a cookie. Every time the webpage loads up, if the client is new, it will alert "You are a stranger, aren't you?" And if a cookie is found when loading the page, it will read the cookie and alert "Hello again + name(which was found as a cookie)."

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var user=getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } else {
    alert("You are a stranger, aren't you?");
  }
}

function pass()
{
    var user = document.getElementById("UNAME").value;
    alert("Your name now will be saved.");
    setCookie("username", user, 1);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="checkCookie()">

<h1>Submission</h1>

<form method = "post" enctype = "text/plain" action="/postplain/">
  <label>First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="UNAME" name="uname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick = "pass()">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This code works, the entered name is saved as a cookie on my device. But how can I read that saved cookie using Esp8266 Webserver from the client device? Or is it possible to do that?

Currently, I have hosted the HTML page using this Arduino code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "your-ssid"
#define STAPSK  "your-pass"
#endif

const char* ssid     = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

IPAddress esppIP(192, 168, 0, 105);  
IPAddress gateway(192, 168,0, 105);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0); 

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const int led = LED_BUILTIN;

const String postForms = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\n<head>\n<script>\nfunction setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {\n  var d = new Date();\n  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));\n  var expires = \"expires=\" + d.toGMTString();\n  document.cookie = cname + \"=\" + cvalue + \";\" + expires + \";path=/\";\n}\n\nfunction getCookie(cname) {\n  var name = cname + \"=\";\n  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);\n  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');\n  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {\n    var c = ca[i];\n    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {\n      c = c.substring(1);\n    }\n    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {\n      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);\n    }\n  }\n  return \"\";\n}\n\nfunction checkCookie() {\n  var user=getCookie(\"username\");\n  if (user != \"\") {\n    alert(\"Welcome again \" + user);\n  } else {\n    alert(\"You are a stranger, aren't you?\");\n  }\n}\n\nfunction pass()\n{\n\tvar user = document.getElementById(\"UNAME\").value;\n    alert(\"Your name now will be saved.\");\n    setCookie(\"username\", user, 1);\n}\n\n</script>\n</head>\n\n<body onload=\"checkCookie()\">\n\n<h1>Submission</h1>\n\n<form method = \"post\" enctype = \"text/plain\" action=\"/postplain/\">\n  <label>First name:</label>\n  <input type=\"text\" id=\"UNAME\" name=\"uname\"><br><br>\n  <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick = \"pass()\">\n</form>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n";

void handleRoot() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  server.send(200, "text/html", postForms);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void handlePlain() {
  if (server.method() != HTTP_POST) {
    digitalWrite(led, 1);
    server.send(405, "text/plain", "Method Not Allowed");
    digitalWrite(led, 0);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led, 1);
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "POST body was:\n" + server.arg("plain"));
    digitalWrite(led, 0);
  }
}


void handleNotFound() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void setup(void) {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(100);
  //changing softAP config and starting the Start AP
  WiFi.config(espIP, gateway, subnet);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");
  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.on("/postplain/", handlePlain);

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void) {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

My esp8266 successfully hosted the page. The first time it loaded up, said "You are a stranger, aren't you?" and when I entered my name and reloaded the page, it said, "Welcome again, Fida." I also disconnected my esp8266 and reconnected again, it still was saying "Welcome again, Fida," which indicates that my name was saved on the device as a cookie. But I need to read the cookie using my ESP8266, store it as a variable in its RAM, then search for related values in an SD card(which I will add later to my board).

I hope that I have successfully explained the case to you. I will be glad if you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: see the SimpleAuthentication example of the ESP8266WebServer library in IDE Examples menu

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.